# Rails app works locally, crashes on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crash, heroku, activesupport

I've been trying to figure out what's going wrong from the logs, but have no idea how to fix it.  Here are the snippets from the logs I'm a little confused as to how to fix.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Could not load SystemTimer >= v1.2.0. Falling back to timeout.rb. SystemTimer is STRONGLY recommended for timeouts in Ruby 1.8.7. See http://ph7spot.com/blog/system-timer-1-2-release for details.

/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:306:in `depend_on': No such file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

and this was at the top of the logs

```
from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
```

According to bundle, the following gems are being used

According to bundle install, the following gems are installed

Using rake (0.9.2) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.3) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.4) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.29) 
Using actionpack (3.0.3) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.2) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.2.19) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Using arel (2.0.10) 
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bson (1.3.1) 
Using bson_ext (1.3.1) 
Using bundler (1.0.18) 
Using carrierwave (0.5.7) 
Using excon (0.6.6) 
Using formatador (0.2.1) 
Using multi_json (1.0.3) 
Using net-ssh (2.1.4) 
Using net-scp (1.0.4) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.0) 
Using ruby-hmac (0.4.0) 
Using fog (0.11.0) 
Using formtastic (1.2.4) 
Using mongo (1.3.1) 
Using plucky (0.3.8) 
Using mongo_mapper (0.9.2) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.3) 
Using rails (3.0.3) 
Using rails3-generators (0.17.4)

Here are the full heroku logs

```
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-19T00:19:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-09-19T00:31:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-09-19T00:31:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-19T00:31:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 42871 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `depend_on'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-09-19T00:31:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-19T00:31:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-09-19T00:40:49+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-09-19T00:40:59+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 50313f5 by naguibs@stanford.edu
2011-09-19T00:40:59+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by naguibs@stanford.edu
2011-09-19T00:40:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-09-19T00:40:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-19T00:41:00+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-09-19T00:41:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 22238 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:304:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `depend_on'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2011-09-19T00:41:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-19T00:41:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem????

Comment: Yes, I don't remember the exact solution, but I believe it was fixed when I specified the exact gem versions that I wanted (heroku had newer incompatible versions)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing. Turns out during development a spec had somehow gotten copied up into into the controllers folder. Didn't have any affect locally, but crashed cedar...

Comment: I think You need to clear your question in easy manner.otherwise your problem explanation create another problem

Comment: I just spent a ton of time trying to track this down, and your answer solved my problem.  I ended up searching my app for "spec_helper" and found that I accidentally saved one of my spec files in the models folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in this line:

```
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:306:in `depend_on': No such file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

It seems that one of your initializers has `require "spec_helper"` in it (or loads a file elsewhere that does the same) and shouldn't. This might have to do with gems in your `Gemfile` that are in the `:test` group that don't get loaded by default on Heroku.

You might try running `bundle install --without test development` locally to reproduce how Heroku is installing the gems. Note that this will be the permanent way that bundle installs gems until you delete the `./.bundle/config` file from your project, so you will want to do that afterwards once you've figured things out.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I couldn't find a file with require "spec_helper" in any of the initializers :(.  I did bundle install --without test development and no errors occured.

Comment: the app ran locally, but still fails on heroku

Comment: @Kyle after you did that. You should execute your commands (such as `rails s`, `rails c`, `rake something`) by prefixing them with `bundle exec`. In this way you're fully reproducing the heroku env. Otherwise your commands still see the "uninstalled" gems.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue with passenger. The problem was a require in a model that depended on a lib. Adding the lib directory to autoload and removing *all* requires (found by `fgrep 'require' -r app/`) worked.